# Date copmarison in SumIfs Formula not working

Tags: excel, vba, date, comparison, sumifs

I try to compare the current date to dates in one column but it gives me "0" all the time.
Before I added the date comparison within the "SumIfs" formula it worked well.

```
Dim ClaimR As Workbook

With ClaimR.Sheets(1).Columns(10) 'Column "J"
    .NumberFormat = "DD.MM.YY"
End With

Dim today As Date
today = Format(Date)


    HoursAmount = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(ClaimR.Sheets(1).Range("I:I"), ClaimR.Sheets(1).Range("G:G"), serial, ClaimR.Sheets(1).Range("U:U"), "Vacation", ClaimR.Sheets(1).Range("J:J"), "<=" & today)
```

I've read some related issues but I don't get what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Try using: `"<=" & CDbl(Date)` as the criterion.

Comment: Wow I have no clue why, but this actually worked!
Why would I change one of two date formats into one double and one date for a comparison?

Thanks anyways

Comment: VBA behaves as though you have US regional settings by default. Converting the date to a Double removes any ambiguity as to month/year order.

Comment: I see! Thanks for your explanation.